# Why Swing application windows look different when debugging vs running from command line?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I developed an application which opens two windows. When I launch the application from the NetBeans IDE I get a certain visual result while when I launch it outside NetBeans the two windows appear larger than needed.
Which are the differences between the two modes?

Comment: *"Which are the differences between the two modes?"* Hard to know without you showing your code

Comment: I'm not at my PC now, I will post the code soon. Independently of the code, it seems strange to me that I get two different sizes of the windows and was thinking more of a difference in settings that I am not aware of. I am perfectly aware that when requesting a certain size of a window, there's no guarantee that the OS would grant it but why the difference between the two "worlds"?

Comment: I see this from time to time. It's often a result of different JVM at the system level (command line) vs. the JVM that is used in NetBeans. If the JVMs are identical, then look at explicitly setting look-and-feel in your app.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Make it the simplest code (a button in a frame?) that shows a difference. 2) Link to two images of the different GUIs.

Comment: If you mean by debugging as to running your application directly from the NetBeans IDE then I believe by Default NetBeans runs applications using the Nimbus Look & Feel, I could however be wrong. If your application is not specifically coded to handle a particular Look & Feel (usually placed within the startup class main() method) then a default Look & Feel is used that is closest related to the Operating System your Java application is run in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JVMs are in alignment.

In NetBeans, go to `Tools` / `Java Platforms`
[image: NetBeans Java Platform Manager]

In this case, mine is 1.8.0 build 221.

Now check at the command line--in my case I have 9.0.4:
[image: Command Line JVM version]

I am pretty confident that Swing stuff will look somewhat different between NetBeans and the command line on my machine at this point.
If I wanted, I could change the configuration in NetBeans to match the command line, or I could change the JVM used at the command line (as I have done in this screenshot).

Comment: That was the difference I was looking for! I tried changing the PATH as suggested but it still pointed to the wrong runtime. A more practical solution I found is changing the \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile registry entry and make it point to the right executable (jre1.8.0_221 or jdk1.8.0_201 in my case).

Comment: On my sytem I have the following installed:
1. jdk-12 (which is the default platform in Netbeans)
2. jdk1.8.0_201 (which is the one used by my project)
3. jre1.8.0_221 (latest runtime)
When I launch the project from Netbeans, it uses n.2 for the runtime (as expected)
*BUT* when I launch it from the Windows explorer, it uses nr.1 !
I changed the registry as above and I'm getting the same behaviour now.